# trying to make slider using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m trying to make a slider using jquery..i downloaded the cycle plugin for my slider and included that too in my file...i m using 7 pic for my slider.. below is the code...please tell what is the problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#hero{width:200px;height:220px;display:block;position:relative;margin:auto;border-style:solid;border-color:grey;}
#slider{width:200px;height:200px;display:block;position:absolute;}
#next{display:block;float:right;height:30px;width:30px;position:relative;z-index:99;cursor:pointer;}
#prev{display:block;float:left;height:30px;width:30px;position:relative;z-index:99;cursor:pointer;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#slider').cycle({

    fx:         'scrollHorz',
    timeout:    2000,
    next:       '#next',
    prev:       '#prev'

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hero">

<div id="prev">
<img src="right.jpg">
</div>

<div id="next">
<img src="left.jpg">
</div>

<div id="slider">
<div id="1"><img  src="1.jpg"></div><br><br>
<div id="2"><img  src="2.jpg"></div><br>
<div id="3"><img  src="3.jpg"></div><br>
<div id="4"><img  src="4.jpg"></div><br>
<div id="5"><img  src="5.jpg"></div><br>
<div id="6"><img src="6.jpg"></div><br>
<div id="7"><img  src="7.jpg"></div><br>
</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Please make an JSFiddle example

Comment: the slideshow is not working....images are not moving when i click left or right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change the position of plugins? Shouldn't `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>` be before `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>`?

Comment: @user3579267 if this answer fixed your problem, you should click Accept.

Comment: JQuery should be before (:

**jquery.cycle.all.js** depends of **jquery-2.1.0.min.js**, not otherwise.